# Number of times a specific pair happens in a combination

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

To get the number of possible combinations I can use:

$$n!/r!(n-r)!$$

But what I need now is to know how many times two specific items (or any other amount of items) are in the same combination, in the whole list. For example:

```
n = 5
r = 3
Result: 
{a,b,c} **
{a,b,d} **
{a,b,e} **
{a,c,d} 
{a,c,e} 
{a,d,e} 
{b,c,d} 
{b,c,e} 
{b,d,e} 
{c,d,e}
```

I have marked with ** the combinations where {a, b} are present, which is 3 times. How can I calculate that?

Thanks

Comment: If you know $a$ and $b$ must be in the combination for you to consider it a "good" one to count, then how many more empty spaces are there available in each combination that you still have to pick more elements for?  Out of how many remaining elements?  $\binom{5-2}{3-2}=\binom{3}{1}=3$

Comment: Thanks @JMoravitz , but I don't understand the solution... How would it work for n=7, r=5 and looking for 3 specific elements in all combinations?

Comment: With $n=7,r=5,k=3$ you have $\binom{n-k}{r-k}=\binom{7-3}{5-3}=\binom{4}{2}$... because with $3$ specific elements you want in your five element set... all you have to do is choose two more elements to go in the set and you have $7-3=4$ elements to choose from.

Comment: Oh all clear now! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose you have a set $\left\{x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_r, x_{r+1}, \ldots, x_n \right\}$ and you want to find the number of subsets containing $k \geq r$ elements, including $x_1, \ldots, x_r$.

You already choose $r$ elements, so you still have to choose $k-r$ other elements from the remaining $n-r$ elements to have a total of $k$ elements. There are $\binom{n-r}{k-r}$ possible ways to do so.